# How to use or extend Django admin to navigate thru aggregated data?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-aggregation

I would like to know how could I extend Django admin in order to be able to navigate the records using aggregated data.

For example: browse data aggregated by date, month, day, day of the week and see average, max/min or total for other fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can [extend the admin templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) to add some charts / reports above the normal changelist, changeform, etc (using model methods or something else).

Also, checkout [databrowse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/). I've not used it, but it might provide an easier way to add aggregation.